postgresql error: Error during planning: Coercion from [Float32, Int64]
Running sql query in app.preset.io system which should use postgresql. The query just calculate precision and recall values from metrics_table, but got
weird error. Ran same sql query use other sql query tool and it works fine.
WITH time_periods AS (
    SELECT year, week, cast(tp as real) as tp , cast(fp as real) as fp,
     cast(tn as real) as tn, cast(fn as real) as fn
    FROM metrics_table  
    WHERE week >= 37    
)
SELECT 
    year,
    week,
    CASE 
        WHEN (tp + fp) = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE ROUND(cast(tp  as real) / (cast(tp as real) + cast(fp as real)), 3)
    END as precision,
    CASE 
        WHEN (tp + fn) = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE ROUND(cast(tp as real) / (cast(tp as real) + cast(fn as real)), 3)
    END as recall
FROM time_periods
ORDER BY year, week

got following error
postgresql error: Error during planning: Coercion from [Float32, Int64] to the signature OneOf([Exact([Float64]), Exact([Float32]), Exact([Decimal(38, 10), Int32])]) failed

It's this part causing the error:
ROUND(cast(tp  as real) / (cast(tp as real) + cast(fp as real)), 3)

Tried to cast the columns to float type or numeric type but still got same error.

These are the round() functions in PostgreSQL:
\df round
                         List of functions
   Schema   │ Name  │ Result data type │ Argument data types │ Type 
════════════╪═══════╪══════════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════
 pg_catalog │ round │ double precision │ double precision    │ func
 pg_catalog │ round │ numeric          │ numeric             │ func
 pg_catalog │ round │ numeric          │ numeric, integer    │ func
(3 rows)

The two-argument form of round() exists only for numeric, but not for real or double precision.
